# using trigger to update another database's table on same server

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to insert record in db2.inventory whenever there is an insert event in db1.sales using triggers.

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertintodb2`;
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
 TRIGGER `insertintodb2` AFTER INSERT ON `sales`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO `db2.dbo.inventory` (ID) VALUES (0);
```

it is giving me error

`db1.db2.dbo.inventory` doesn't exist.

how can i make this work.
thank you

Comment: Remove the quotes from the last line of code.

Comment: tried that it's giving syntax error.

Comment: Try to remove .dbo too

Comment: did that it gave me error. it's adding db1 to it automatically.

Comment: Remove quotes and .dbo 
Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) quotes (backtick) are used to identify objects names, but you must use them on every single object:

```
`db2`.`dbo`.`inventory`
```

or without them if object names are not misleading:

```
db2.dbo.inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB do not use the `.dbo.` syntax.  There is only database (aka schema) name and table name:

```
db2.inventory
```

or

```
`db2`.`inventory`
```

(The presence or absence of backtics does not matter in *this* situation.)

Comment: @Nilay_ - Please note that I have 4 backtics, not 2.  Please update your question to show the test case without `dbo`, together with the exact error message.